# python match exclamation mark in mutiline

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that has a repeated pattern output

```
!-----------------------------------------------------------------
line 1
line 2
line 3
.....
-------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

I am trying to match and extract all the occurrences of these blocks but the below returns all the file

```
match = re.search(r'\!-.*-\!', data, re.DOTALL)
print match.group()
```

Comment: Try putting a question mark after the `*`: `r'\!-.*?-\!'`. Also, I don't know why there would be a need to escape exclamation marks, as far as I know they have no special function in regular expressions.

Comment: @L3viathan That didn't work either...I still get the whole file both on group() and group(0).

Comment: Make sure to use the `re.DOTALL` flag, as shown in Honza Zíka's answer. [Demo of the working pattern](https://regex101.com/r/zlGpBt/1)

Comment: @L3viathan Please see my code in the question. I do use DOTALL

Comment: a) Use `!-.*?-!` instead of your pattern. b) Use `re.findall` (gives you a list) or `re.finditer` (gives you an iterator; maybe better for huge files) instead of `re.search`.

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks for the comments...Finally that made it work `match = re.findall(r'!-.*?-!', data, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

Regexes in Python are greedy by default, meaning `*` will consume as many characters as possible. You can turn off greediness by using `*?`:

```
match = re.search(r'\!-.*?-\!', data, re.DOTALL)
```